# Spring Security form login styling without JSP

Tags: spring-security

I have a Spring Security application with a form-login:

```
<security:http>
    <security:form-login ... />
</security:http>
```

The login pages are working very well for me, but I'm getting complaints the lack of just a minimum amount of styling. I understand styling can be added through a few JSP pages, but I'm wondering if it is possible to somehow just configure the CSS that I want to use on the whatever bean Spring instantiates for generating the on-the-fly login page.

Comment: Wondering why this is downvoted. It's a serious question, and a real problem/obstacle for my project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default login page is generated in

```
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ui.DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter
```

class and it is basic HTML without any CSS classes. You could create your own page generator filter and include it in filter chain.

BUT this seems more like overkill for something really simple like creating your own login page/form.

Comment: This is the answer that I was looking for. It gives me the option to make an informed choice. I felt there was value in not introducing JSP page(s). But the lack of extensibility of the `DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter` may prompt me to do so after all. Thank you.